# Bad formatting ruby code in Vim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vim, formatting

When I format a PHP file in vim it's ok, but when I format a Ruby file, VIM format code bad.

For example:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

                skip_before_filter :authorize, :only => [ :index, :show ]

  def index
        @posts = Post.all
     end

  def show
    @post = Post.find(:first, :conditions => [ "id = ?", params[:id]], :include => [ :user, :category, :gallery ])
                  @photos = Photo.where(:gallery_id => @post.gallery.id).all
      end
   end
```

When I enter the command **gg=G**, I get.

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

skip_before_filter :authorize, :only => [ :index, :show ]

def index
@posts = Post.all
end

def show
@post = Post.find(:first, :conditions => [ "id = ?", params[:id]], :include => [ :user, :category, :gallery ])
@photos = Photo.where(:gallery_id => @post.gallery.id).all
end
end
```

Please help me.

Comment: are you using vim ruby? that might help : https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get Ruby indenting working you need to provide indenting configuration. Vim itself is not able to indent Ruby code, you could set the indentexpr variable to some similar language (like basic), but you wont be happy with results. Check your smartindent and indentexpr variables:

```
:set si?
:set indentexpr?
```

In my case they are set:

```
nosmartindent
indentexpr=GetRubyIndent()
```

The best way to configure vim for ruby is to use vim-ruby plugin: https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby

Comment: Okey, I installed this plugin and what now? What should I do to fix bad formatting? Sorry, but I newbie.

Comment: You can tell Vim to indent some code with the `=` motion - for example, `=10j` to indent the next 10 lines, or `=G` to indent to the end of the file. Once you've installed a plugin or otherwise told Vim how to format some code, you can use this to fix poorly-indented code. Note that 1) you have to restart Vim after adding a plugin and 2) indenting depends on filetype detection. vim-ruby [detects most Ruby files](https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby/blob/master/ftdetect/ruby.vim) but you can add your own ftdetect file, too.

Answer (score 0):

A more general formatting plugin exists, called [vim-autoformat](https://github.com/vim-autoformat/vim-autoformat).
Among others, it integrates [rbeautify](https://github.com/erniebrodeur/ruby-beautify) to provide stronger formatting than just fixing indentation.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I have any Vim plugins, because I use it at work (and was already installed). However, for what it's worth, here's some of my `.vimrc` file.

```
syntax enable             " Enable syntax highlighting
syntax on
set expandtab             " Use spaces instead of tabs
set shiftwidth=2          " 1 tab == 4 spaces
set tabstop=2             " 1 tab == 4 spaces
```

I actually have `set smartindent` commented out in the file. [[1]](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Indenting_source_code#.27smartindent.27_and_.27cindent.27)

If you want replace any tab-character with spaces (set in the above `.vimrc`), I suggest the following command in your working file: `set :retab` [[2]](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Converting_tabs_to_spaces)